# Advice on SQL query (mine seems to overcomplicate and even spits out scalar subquery error)

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm using SQL developer (oracle sql).

The query below spits out the error:
"Subquery for one line returns more than one line"

Please advice on query logic. I don't expect anybody to solve it for me. Tell me where I am wrong with my thinking.

Given a table which gives the following data:

```
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| PS_NAME | SIDE | WO_NUM  | LOT_PREFIX | PLAIN_LOT | AB_SPLIT |
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| ...     | ..   | ...     |    ...     |  ...      |     .    |
| ANW216  | TO   | 5041092 |    VNAN    |  ANW216   |     x    |
| ANW217  | TO   | 4897524 |    VNAN    |  ANW217   |     x    |
| ANW218  | TO   | 5041093 |    VNAN    |  ANW218   |     x    |
| ANW219  | TO   | 5064069 |    VNAN    |  ANW219   |     x    |
| ANW219A | TO   | 5064097 |    VNAN    |  ANW219A  |     A    |
| ANW220  | TO   | 5064070 |    VNAN    |  ANW220   |     x    |
| ANW220A | TO   | 5064098 |    VNAN    |  ANW220A  |     A    |
| ANW221  | TO   | 5064071 |    VNAN    |  ANW221   |     x    |
| ANW221A | TO   | 5064099 |    VNAN    |  ANW221A  |     A    |
| ANW222  | TO   | 5064072 |    VNAN    |  ANW222   |     x    |
| ANW223  | TO   | 5062459 |    VNAN    |  ANW223   |     x    |
| ...     | ..   | ...     |    ...     |  ...      |     .    |
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

Desired result:

```
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| PS_NAME | SIDE | WO_NUM  | LOT_PREFIX | PLAIN_LOT | AB_SPLIT |
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
| ...     | ..   | ...     |    ...     |  ...      |     .    |
| ANW216  | TO   | 5041092 |    VNAN    |  ANW216   |     x    |
| ANW217  | TO   | 4897524 |    VNAN    |  ANW217   |     x    |
| ANW218  | TO   | 5041093 |    VNAN    |  ANW218   |     x    |
| ANW219A | TO   | 5064097 |    VNAN    |  ANW219A  |     A    |
| ANW220A | TO   | 5064098 |    VNAN    |  ANW220A  |     A    |
| ANW221A | TO   | 5064099 |    VNAN    |  ANW221A  |     A    |
| ANW222  | TO   | 5064072 |    VNAN    |  ANW222   |     x    |
| ANW223  | TO   | 5062459 |    VNAN    |  ANW223   |     x    |
| ...     | ..   | ...     |    ...     |  ...      |     .    |
+---------+------+---------+------------+-----------+----------+
```

What I want to achieve: If there is a lot with A, then just give me the one with A; and do not show the non-A;
So, give me ANW219A only (and ignore ANW219)

Here is the logic behind my query:

```
"Give me the PS_NAME,
   Case, when there is a truncated name (in table t2)
      which is also in table t3
   Then give me this lot with letter A
   Else give me the regular (non-A) lot"
```

From a first point of view this problem seems very easy but I just don't  get where I want to be. And, my gut tells me that my query is probably way to complicated.

```
SELECT
            CASE
                WHEN (
                    SELECT
                        substr(lot, 0, length(lot) - 1)
                    FROM
                        table t2
                    WHERE
                            t1.wo_num = t2.wo_num
                        AND lot_prefix <> 'x'
                        AND side = 'TO'
                        AND ab_split <> 'x'
                ) IN (
                    SELECT
                        lot
                    FROM
                        table t3
                    WHERE
                            t1.wo_num = t3.wo_num
                        AND lot_prefix <> 'x'
                        AND side = 'TO'
                        AND ab_split = 'x'
                )
        --lot
                 THEN
            --t2.lot
                    'THEN'
                ELSE
            --t1.lot
                    'else'
            END ps_name
        FROM
            (
                SELECT
                    lot,
                    ps_date,
                    mcu,
                    wo_num,
                    srp3,
                    lot_core,
                    lot_prefix,
                    plain_lot,
                    ab_split
                FROM
                    table
                WHERE
                        lot_prefix <> 'x'
                    AND side = 'TO'
                    AND ab_split = 'x'
            ) t1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do it, depending on how the `WHERE` clause interacts with other rows in the table:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
        row_number() over (partition by substr(ps_name, 1, 6) order by substr(ps_name, 1, 6), wo_num desc) as rn
    FROM "table" t1
    WHERE Side = 'TO' AND lot_prefix<>'X'
) t
WHERE rn=1
```

Or to more explicitly match the stated logic:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT t1.*,
        row_number() over (
          partition by substr(ps_name, 1, 6) 
          order by case when substr(ps_name 7, 1) = 'A' then 0 else 1 end
         ) as rn
    FROM "table" t1
    WHERE Side = 'TO' AND lot_prefix<>'X'
) t
WHERE rn=1
```

Comment: In both queries I get the error message: "FROM keyword not found where expected" (line where "*,". Is your query meant to replace my whole query or just a part of it?

Comment: Give "table" an alias (e.g. "t"), and use it with asterisk. `... from (select t.*, row_number() ... as rn from "table" t where side ...`

Comment: done and works. I'll need to re-check the result with my colleague before marking it as answer. But so far it shows what it is supposed to :)

Comment: Received results aree correct, thanks for the quick reply. We discussed it but don't completely understand what is going on in this query. Could someone please elaborate on the query and explain what actually happens exactly in the process?

Comment: It uses a Windowing function. Windowing functions are relatively new (only really around since around 2012), but they can really help with certain kinds of queries, including improving performance. Try running the inner query by itself. That will help you understand how it works.